# How can I get the mean of the column by the variable name?

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a a dataframe like:

```
Col_name  Col_X    Col_Y    Col_Z
BoB         2        3          3    
BoB         3        4          3
Carl        4        5          2
Carl        2        3          3
Eva         5        2          5
Bob         1        1          2
```

I want to get the mean of each column by the name. So I want to get this df:

```
Col_name   Col_X    Col_Y      Col_Z
 BOB       2        2.33       2,33
 Carl      3        4          2,5
 Eva       5        2          5
```

Does anyone knows how to to this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach with `dplyr` (BTW - Since you have different cases for names, I am not sure how you got your output, but I convert them to all lower case to get the desired output):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Col_name = tolower(Col_name)) %>%
  group_by(Col_name) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Output as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

  Col_name Col_X    Col_Y    Col_Z
     <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1      bob     2 2.666667 2.666667
2     carl     3 4.000000 2.500000
3      eva     5 2.000000 5.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use package `dplyr` and do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Col_name = c("Bob", "Bob", "Carl", "Carl"), 
                 Col_X = c(2,3,4,2), Col_Y = c(3,4,5,3))
df %>% group_by(Col_name) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(.)))
```

You are taking the data (`df`) group them by the column `Col_name` and then apply the function `mean` on each column and for all distinct groups.

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

  Col_name Col_X Col_Y
    (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)
1      Bob   2.5   3.5
2     Carl   3.0   4.0
```

Comment: Oooops....looks like we both just posted a very similar answer right at the same time.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of upper/lower case names in `Col_name` (look at the Bobs in the example)

Comment: Well I see a difference of 2 minutes there :P

Comment: Did I miss the point or not? Question is not explicit about that...

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(Col_name = c(rep("Bob", 2), rep("Carl", 2), "Eva", "Bob"),
                Col_X = runif(6),
                Col_Y = runif(6),
                Col_Z = runif(6))

 a %>% 
  group_by(Col_name) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Comment: all had the same idea, so it seems :-)

Answer (score 0):

With package `data.table` you can do

```
# creating example data
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Col_name = c("Bob", "Bob", "Carl", "Carl"), Col_X = c(2,3,4,2), Col_Y = c(3,4,5,3))

# aggregate
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = Col_name]
```

which returns:

```
   Col_name Col_X Col_Y
1:      Bob   2.5   3.5
2:     Carl   3.0   4.0
```